# New errors with Theme in project that formerly worked

Tags: android, android-studio, themes

Just checked out my project and am getting new errors. I've tried several solutions proposed for similar problems but nothing has worked.

Here's the error message from Android Studio v. 3.1.3:

error: resource style/AppTheme.ActionBar (aka name.xxxx.myappname:style/AppTheme.ActionBar) not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource style/AppTheme.ActionBar (aka name.xxxx.myappname:style/AppTheme.ActionBar) not found., sources=[/Users/yyyy/StudioProjects/MyAppName/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:37], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}

Here's the offending line from the manifest: 
`android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar">`

(`@style/AppTheme.ActionBar` is in red with a "cannot resolve symbol" message)

And here are the 3 offending lines from `styles.xml`:

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

`<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />`

`<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />`

The words `Theme` and `ThemeOverlay` are colored red.

What's causing this new error, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I got rid of the error in the manifest by defining a dummy (empty) `AppTheme.ActionBar` in `styles.xml`. Further research indicates that if your Activity extends AppCompatActivity (like mine does) then you need to use `Theme.AppCompat.whatever` and `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.whatever`. So this looks correct. Android Studio just refuses to locate these. I've played with different versions of the support lib, invalidating caches, everything else that's been suggested—no change.